# Task(s) inside SwiftUI View Struct

Tags: swiftui, task

I have buttons that reveive a `Tutorial` type and thus look and behave differently.

```
struct CircleButtonView: View {

   @State var value: CGFloat = 0 // animation value
    
   let tutorial: Tutorial

   ...

}
```

The first button shakes and after the user clicks, a tutorial is displayed. After that, the second button shakes etc.

Therefore, i have this function, which updates the animation state upon several conditions:

```
private func update(tutorial: Tutorial?) {
    Task { @MainActor in        
        switch tutorial {
            case .boost:
                guard !Defaults.Tutorials.Discover.Boost else {
                    return
                }
            
            case .dislike:
                guard !Defaults.Tutorials.Discover.Dislike else {
                    return
                }
            
            case .superlike:
                guard !Defaults.Tutorials.Discover.Superlike else {
                    return
                }
            
            case .like:
                guard !Defaults.Tutorials.Discover.Like else {
                    return
                }
            
            case .friendzone:
                guard !Defaults.Tutorials.Discover.Friendzone else {
                    return
                }
            
            default:
                return
        }
        
        try self.delay()
        
        switch value { // this updates the buttons one after another ...
            case .dislike:
                guard Defaults.Tutorials.Discover.Boost else {
                    return // boost not done (yet)
                }
            
            case .superlike:
                guard Defaults.Tutorials.Discover.Boost,
                      Defaults.Tutorials.Discover.Dislike
                else {
                    return // boost and/ or dislike not done (yet)
                }
            
            case .like:
                guard Defaults.Tutorials.Discover.Boost,
                      Defaults.Tutorials.Discover.Dislike,
                      Defaults.Tutorials.Discover.Superlike
                else {
                    return // boost and/ or dislike and/ or superlike not done (yet)
                }
            
            case .friendzone:
                guard Defaults.Tutorials.Discover.Boost,
                      Defaults.Tutorials.Discover.Dislike,
                      Defaults.Tutorials.Discover.Superlike,
                      Defaults.Tutorials.Discover.Like
                else {
                    return // boost and/ or dislike and/ or superlike and/ or like not done (yet)
                }
            
            default:
                return
        }
                                
        self.value = 0 // no animation, set to 0 ...
        
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
            self.value = 6.0 // ... animate to 6
        }
    }
}
```

This function is called in the `update` function to animate the shake every 2s:

```
func delay() throws {
    Task {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2_000_000_000) // not on main thread ...
        
        self.update(tutorial: tutorial) // update (if needed)
    }
}
```

Now, this all works fine. However, normally i would use `[weak self]` in the task, so there are no memory leaks, in structs this is not possible. How can i make sure my delay task won't call `update` if the view is not there anymore (as it currently executes `update` even if the view disappears ...)

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73805317/7129318) for an interesting take.

Comment: Don’t use those floating Task, it defeats the greatness of async await. Always hold on to the Task so you know where it is and you can cancel. SwiftUI comes built in with .task, it cancels any tasks automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI, it's [task(id:priority:_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(id:priority:_:)) not `Task { }`, e.g.

```
.task(id: tutorial) {
    do {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2_000_000_000)
    }
    catch {
        return // cancelled
    }
    update(tutorial)
}
```